# how to trigger something immediately then debounce

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an observable bound to event keyUp on an input box.

For each key pressed. I want to console.log 'Do something now'.

And if there's no key pressed for 5 seconds, then I want to console.log 'Do something else'

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const searchBox = document.getElementById('search');

const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'keyup')

keyup$.pipe(
  switchMap((i: any) => 'doSomethingNow'), // I use switchMap here because 'doSomethingNow' is an http request in my real code so that on each key pressed, it cancels the previous http request if it was not finished and start the new http request
  debounceTime(2000),
  map(_ => 'do something else')
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

This code only print 'do something after debounce' after 5 seconds but never print 'domethingNow' after each key pressed

Comment: so you want to http request on every key pressed? that's what happen if you put in before debounce

Comment: on every key press, there's an http request and if there no key pressed for 5 sec. I want to console.log 'do something else'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the merge operator:

```
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search');

const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'keyup');

const keyupEnd$ = keyup$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => debounceTime(500))
);

const result = merge(
  keyup$,
  keyupEnd$
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

var searchBox  = document.getElementById('search');

var keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox , 'keyup')      

keyup$.pipe(
  switchMap((i: any) => { console.log('do something');})
  debounceTime(5000)) // with delay of 5 secs
  .subscribe(console.log('do something else'););
```

Comment: I can't do that, Im using redux observable.